# How to handle key press and up & key down?

Tags: c#, winforms, key, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a class that catches keyboard keys and I want to catch a specific combination:

```
Alt + 1
```

And in case this combination is detected to do my stuff.

This is what I have try:

```
private bool isAltPressed;
private bool isOnePressed;
private bool bothPressed;

private void HookManager_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LMenu)
        isAltPressed = true;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
        isOnePressed = true;
    if (isAltPressed & isOnePressed)
        bothPressed = true;
}

private void HookManager_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (bothPressed)
        // Do something...

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LMenu)
    {
        isAltPressed = false;
        bothPressed = false;
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
    {
        isOnePressed = false;
        bothPressed = false;
    }
}
```

So where do I need to verify that both keys are pressed and released and then do my stuff?

Comment: What is `HookManager`? Which events are your event handlers for?

Comment: This is the class the catch every key press or release

Comment: Why do we need to guess what's in there? You have to provide a [mcve] so your question can be answered.

Comment: Usually you trigger an action either in key down OR key up. Set `e.Handled = true;` to suppress the normal key handling by winforms. See: [KeyEventArgs Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs?view=netframework-4.8). You can also use [Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keyboard.iskeydown?view=netframework-4.8) to test the status of a key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ( e.KeyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.D1) )
```

Keys is a struct having a flag attribute.

It means that several key codes can be combinated with the logic or operator to form the result.

```
[Flags]
public enum Keys ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not wait for alt key to be released to perform your action. Unless you can explain why you need to make sure both the alt key and the key pressed must be released before 'doing something', the following code should suffice in either your `KeyUp` or `KeyDown` event.

```
if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
{
    // Do Something
}
```